# How to merge polymorphic results of a child and parent together with a has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 models named **User, Photo and Report**

Model `Report` is a polymorphic class and is used to report users and photos and model `User` has a polymorphic association with the Modal `Photo`.

> So the functionality is a user can report photos or any other users.

below is the migration file of `Report`.

```
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :reported_id
      t.string :reported_type, default: "User"
      t.string :note, default: ""
    end
 end
end
```

and below are the associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :photos, as: :attachment
  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :attachment, :polymorphic: true
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :reported, polymorphic: true
end
```

currently i use a query like below to get reported list of a user either by the user itself or by their photos.

```
 Report.where("(reported_id=? AND reported_type=?) OR (reported_id in (?) AND reported_type=?)", 
  self.id, "User", self.photos.pluck(:id), "Photo")
```

So, i would like to know how can i achieve same thing with an has_many association ?

Please help me if there is any better way which i can achieve the same or correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Rails are smart enough to use argument's class in filtration by a polymorphic association. You may rewrite your condition in a very simple way:

```
Report.where(reported: [self] + self.photos)

# result sql
SELECT  "reports".* 
FROM "reports" 
WHERE (
  ("reports"."reported_type" = 'User' AND "reports"."reported_id" = 1) OR 
  ("reports"."reported_type" = 'Photo' AND "reports"."reported_id" IN (1, 2))
)
```

This code works only in Rails 5.x.

**Update**

In Rails 4.2 this code will not work. You may check related SO questions: [Finding record where polymorphic association or nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200091/finding-record-where-polymorphic-association-or-nil) and [OR operator in WHERE clause with Arel in Rails 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627390/or-operator-in-where-clause-with-arel-in-rails-4-2)

I think, your current code is the best you can do in Rails 4.2

Comment: Thanks for the output but this return query like this for me `SELECT `reports`.* FROM `reports` WHERE `reports`.`reported_type` = 'User' AND `reports`.`reported_id` IN (273, 932, 1215, 1216, 1217)` i guess only user is picking from this.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: i'm using rails 4.2.4